# Which nodeJS version does Node Webkit use?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webkit, node-serialport

I am new to Node Webkit, so I might not entirely understand how NodeJS and Node Webkit is connected.

I am trying to get the [serialport](https://github.com/EmergingTechnologyAdvisors/node-serialport) plugin work in Node Webkit. I get this error when trying to `require("serialport");`:

```
serialport.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 48. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 57. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module...
```

I've tried recompiling and all that - doesn't work. So I would rather just downgrade to a node version that fits. Problem is that if I type `node -v` in my terminal I get `v6.10.1`, which according to [this](https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/) should be `NODE_MODULE_VERSION 48`.

So I am confused when the error tells me that it is using 57. Does Node Webkit use another NodeJS version than the one installed on my computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the Node Webkit release notes:

> Update Node.js to v8.6.0

https://nwjs.io/blog/v0.25.4/

Node Webkit requires v8.6.0 and you have installed v6.10.1. The serialport module according to [this](https://github.com/EmergingTechnologyAdvisors/node-serialport#platform-support) can be used with Node >= v4.x.x. Upgrade node on your local system and try again.

Maybe a `npm install` is needed? You tried that?

Comment: Node Webkit worked fine - which means that NW comes with the correct version of NodeJS. Problem was that my computer and the global node and npm was v6.10.1 and therefore npm installed a version of serialport that worked with v6.10.1 and not v8.6.0. I fixed it by upgrading the system installed node and reinstalled serialport :) .

Comment: Nice to here :) I ran into similar problem with an RPi3 and serialport - but the error msg is confusing ...